# register desktop application shorcut key in shell of window

Tags: c#, vb.net, desktop-application

I want to register my desktop application shortcut in windows shell.so that if my desktop application is in minimized mode then i want to run the shortcut key i.e is set by me in desktop application that i have created.
My main motive is that when my application is in minimized mode then i want to run  a shortcut key  to take screenshot of active screen.
I have tried the below code that will minimized my desktop application.

```
public TemplatesCreation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            trayMenu = new ContextMenu();
            trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Exit", OnExit);
            trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
            trayIcon.Text = "MyTrayApp";
            trayIcon.Icon = new Icon(SystemIcons.Application, 40, 40);
            trayIcon.ContextMenu = trayMenu;
            trayIcon.Visible = true;

 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            Visible = true; // Hide form window.
            ShowInTaskbar = false; // Remove from taskbar.
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }

        private void OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you'd have to write a keyboard hook to have your own shortcut, or you can hook into one of the standard shortcuts, like ctrl shift p. these are monitored by windows. But, it may be easier to monitor the clipboard, so a user presses print screen, and it stores the screenshot in the clipboard. you can then save it from there? (never tried it, but there's no reason why it wouldn't work)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/330837/ScreenCap-CSharp-Screen-Capture-Application link to a project that looks like a good place to start. hooks into print screen button

Comment: @SmithMart thanks a lot smith above link is really helpfull for me